# How to check if my repository has been deployed to heroku?

Tags: heroku, deployment, repository

I have several repositories and only one has been deployed to heroku. How do I find out which one? Because I made a change in one repo and tried to push it but got a warning `fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository`. Is there a command?

Comment: What is the command you're running that returns `fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository`?

Comment: `git push heroku master`

Comment: I suspect that you have not pushed this repo before. It's trying to push to a remote called `heroku` which is automatically added when you run `heroku create` from the directory.

Try running `git remote -v` in the various repos until you find one with a heroku remote. That will be the one that you've pushed to.

Comment: There is another way to check: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/production-check

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have not created heroku repository yet or you are in wrong directory. Go to the directory where you have your app then create heroku with the help of below commands.

```
git init

heroku create
```

after creating heroku you can add and commit heroku with the help of

`git add .`

`git commit -am "any comment"`

last step will be to push all your data to heroku server by

`git heroku push master`

If repository is already created, you can check associated repository by hitting below command

```
$ git remote -v
```

You may need to run `heroku git:remote` command to associate a Git repository with an existing application

for more information on how to deploy app [click here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git)